# How i can get all query in one field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables like this:

First :

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

Second:

| id | first_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | a1 |
| 12 | 1 | a2 |
| 13 | 1 | a3 |

And I need to get result like this:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a1-a2-a3 |

I've tried with query:

```
SELECT first.id, (SELECT second.value FROM second
  WHERE second.first_id = first.id) AS value
FROM first
```

But I've got #1242 error. How I can do it?

Comment: something wrong with tables in text

Comment: I fixed, do not worry

Comment: @Beso thnx a lot!

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: According to the error it is probably MySQL. I am going to tag that.

Comment: Do you only want second_table data in your result?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_concat()`

```
select first_id as id, 
       group_concat(`value` order by `value` separator '-') as combined_values
FROM second_table
group by first_id
```